Better way of passing an array into overloaded method
The program I am working with is providing me with an array of int values. These need to be passed into a method that is overloaded to take either two, three or four ints.
I am using the following, but am dissatisfied with the style. Alternative suggestions?
public static void customAdd(String name, BComponent parent, BComponent child, int[]locations, String[]link) {
    //add object
    parent.add(name, child);

    //configure locations
    if (locations.length > 0) {
        BWsAnnotation annotation;
        switch (locations.length) {
        case 2:
            child.add("WsAnnotation", BWsAnnotation.make(locations[0], locations[1]));
            break;
        case 3:
            child.add("WsAnnotation", BWsAnnotation.make(locations[0], locations[1], locations[2]));
            break;
        case 4:
            child.add("WsAnnotation", BWsAnnotation.make(locations[0], locations[1], locations[2], locations[3]));
            break;
        }
    }
}


Is BWsAnnotation your own method, or does it belong to some third-party library? Can you show us the method declaration?

From a search, I gather this method is part of the Niagara Framework, which I have never heard of before (and I expect very few people know it). Therefore can you share a link to the Javadoc of its API?

Sounds like the APIs need modernising with varargs! They've been around since Java 5 AFAIK!

You could use var-args in the BWsAnnotation#make method, but then you would have to deconstruct the array there.
With Java 17, this should be the most readable solution, inlining the switch, and omitting the braces:
//configure locations
child.add("WsAnnotation", switch (locations.length) {
    case 2 -> BWsAnnotation.make(locations[0], locations[1]));
    case 3 -> BWsAnnotation.make(locations[0], locations[1], locations[2]));
    case 4 -> BWsAnnotation.make(locations[0], locations[1], locations[2], locations[3]));
    default -> throw new IllegalStateException(/* Error Message */);
});

Relying on different array sizes for arguments is non-optimal style, from my point of view. Maybe try to refactor this 3 Types of arrays into Objects with the same parent class/interface.

I think that the make function is the one you should modify, it should rather take in an array as an argument rather than being overloaded, if that overcomplicated things, you can try to use the Java reflextion API as the following post answers.

Using reflection for this purpose is unstable. If the name or number of args on the BWsAnnotation#make changes, the code will fail at runtime.
